# Firestore Collection Doesn't retrieve expected output

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react native function to to get all collection documents as follows

```
export const fetchAuctionItems = () => {
   return firestore().collection('items').get();
};
```

When I'm accessing above function response not getting any documents instead that I'm getting following

[image]

Can anyone one help me to solve my problem, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`collection.get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) returns a a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) and this is the data you are seeing. You need to request the data from the QuerySnapshot, like so for example.

```js
export const fetchAuctionItems = () => {
  return firestore().collection('items')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => querySnapshot
      .docs
      .map(d => ({
        id: d.id,
        ...d.data(),
      });
};
```

Read more about QuerySnapshot [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)